# SavedInstanceState is always null even though it has an id

Tags: android, android-activity, android-savedstate

I found many answers to this problem, but none of them seem to work. This is the code in the `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putString(CUR_TASK, curTask);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

as you see, `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)` is at the end, so it should work. My layout does have an `id`, so that should be OK too:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
```

still, when I call `startActivity` to go to another `Activity` and return back (using the `ActionBar`), the `savedInstanceState` bundle in `onCreate` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html):

> Note: Because onSaveInstanceState() is not guaranteed to be called, you should use it only to record the transient state of the activity (the state of the UI)—you should never use it to store persistent data. Instead, you should use onPause() to store persistent data (such as data that should be saved to a database) when the user leaves the activity.

The method `onSaveInstanceState` is not used for your purpose, it's used in a case like screen rotation to save UI state.
You have to switch your logic passing the values through the intent when the first `Activity` launches the second one and passing the values back again using `onActivityResult()`.

In addition, I recommend you to restore your state not in `onCreate()` but in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in which you are ALWAYS sure that your `savedInstanceState` `Bundle` isn't null.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is in fact called. I do not want to store persistent data. The `Activity` has some data it received from the internet, and when going to another activity and coming back, that data is gone. I want to retrieve it again: retrieve the state of the UI.

Comment: @BartFriederichs as I said, you have to move your logic to onActivityResult(). I know that onSaveInstanceState is called, but onRestoreInstanceState isn't

Comment: Should I also start it with `startActivityForResult` for that to work? It is kind of strange though, because I do not really ask for a result. The logic is more like "show a complete email from a list of emails".

Answer (score 0):

If the instance state in onCreate is not null when you background the app and come back my guess would be that when you go back to an activity from the back stack it is recreated.

Set your Activity launch mode to singleTop for great justice
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)